# Automatically open Chrome developer tools when new tab/new window is opened

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have an HTML5 application which opens in a new window each time I click on a link. I'm a bit tired of pressing **Shift + I** command each time I want to log network communication to launch **Developer tools** because I need it always. I was not able to find an option to keep Developer Tools always enabled on startup.

Is there any way to open **Developer tools** automatically when new window is opened in Chrome?

Comment: I would love to know this as well. Only way I've found is to edit the source like this guy did: [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/HhwKHUryNaA

Comment: I've scoured pretty hard, and the closest thing I can find is the create a new Pane inside the dev tools, with a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Using SendKeys with Python, you can launch Chrome and send `+^j` to simulate Ctrl Shift J, but that would only work with a new instance; you'd have to get a bit more creative with selenium or something in order to navigate to a given page...

Comment: Yeah, I also saw this variant but it is not applicable when you what to open dev tools for each new tab opened.

Comment: [Here's a guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/HhwKHUryNaA) who modified the source code to add this capability. It appears to be out of date now, but at least we know your request is *possible*.

Comment: This feature was added in 2016. See here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958#c81

Comment: @Rimian great link! Nitpick though... it's the comment 78 above the one you link to that is more relevant I think: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958#c78

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366206/2238544) .  - 2019-11-05

You can also now have it auto-open Developer Tools in Pop-ups if they were open where you opened them from. For example, if you do not have Dev Tools open and you get a popup, it won't open with Dev Tools. But if you Have Dev Tools Open and then you click something, the popup will have Dev-Tools Automatically opened.

**UPDATE:**

Time has changed, you can now use --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#36957422) – Wouter Huysentruit May 18 at 11:08

**OP:**

I played around with the startup string for Chrome on execute, but couldn't get it to persist to new tabs.
I also thought about a defined PATH method that you could invoke from prompt. This is possible with the SendKeys command, but again, only on a new instance. And DevTools doesn't persist to new tabs.

Browsing the Google Product Forums, there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do this in Chrome. You'll have to use a keystroke solution or <kbd>F12</kbd> as mentioned above.

I recommended it as a feature. I know I'm not the first either.

Comment: @Seanny123: fixed!
If you want this as a feature, feel free to Star this Chromium bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958

Comment: @Chiperific, you said you was playing around the startup string for Chrome on execute, but could not get it to persist to new tabs. I need this behavior on startup for only one tab, however. Can you share the way you did it for one tab only?

Comment: Time has changed, you can now use `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36957422/1300910)

Comment: Please consider editing your answer. It is obsolete but still very visible in SO.

Comment: The full command for OS X is (quit any running Chrome process first): `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

Answer (score 422):

On opening the developer tools, with the developer tools window in focus, press <kbd>F1</kbd>. This will open a settings page. Check the "Auto-open DevTools for popups".

This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: This works and is exactly what the OP was asking, it should be marked as the right answer

Comment: Also doesn't work for me with WebStorm. The page opens but no dev tools.

Comment: It worked for me. Opening the console open, I clicked a link on my page which opens in a new tab and then it opened with a console. Thanks.

Comment: This works, but the "Preserve Logs" option is always unchecked, and if the popup redirects it doesn't show previous network requests. Any ideas how to make it preserve logs by default?

Comment: This only works for a specific subset of cases, please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958#c87. It's not a general solution.

Comment: Doesn't work when starting from VS Code with Chome debug extension.

Comment: In Preferences, there are no `DevTools`. My version is Ubuntu Snap `Version 84.0.4147.105 (Offizieller Build) snap (64-Bit)`

Comment: @VanAlbert See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386381/7660079  (Sorry late reply lol)

Comment: This option in combination with [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement to pause in the newly opened window works for me.

Comment: This little tweak has an amazingly large effect on my sanity.  When doing dev, especially with frameworks like React and NextJS, the dev tools are open 100% of the time. 
 Being able to automatically open for popup interactions means I don't have to try and race faster than the system can perform component redirects and output can be captured, debuggers can be handled, etc.

Answer (score 151):

There is a command line switch for this: `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

So, on Windows, for the properties on Google Chrome shortcut, use something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

Here is a useful link:
[chromium-command-line-switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

As per [the DevTools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#auto), here's the commands for each platform from the command line:

- MacOS:

  ```
  open -a "Google Chrome" --args --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  start chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
  ```
- Linux:

  ```
  google-chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
  ```

Comment: This definitely works and should probably be marked as accepted answer now. Checked for chromium `Version 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit)` and opened it like this `chromium-browser --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 7 Version 51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: The full command for OS X is (quit any running Chrome process first): `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

Comment: Didn't work on Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Works in my use case unlike Saint's answer.

Comment: Remember to quit all Chrome instances before trying this. Or this won't work.

Comment: I updated the command line arguments to this: --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=c:\temp\chrome. This essentially tells Chrome to use a separate directory just for debugging and did the trick for me

Comment: Thanks for that hint, @BrianWells !

Comment: For reference here is the issue thread for when it was added to Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410958#c78 (first noted in [question comment from @Rimian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#comment75102404_12212504))

Answer (score 38):

On a Mac: Quit Chrome, then run the following command in a terminal window:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

Comment: To clarify: this opens Chrome with the `auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag set. Quitting Chrome and reopening it using the normal application shortcut will open Chrome without the flag set.

If you want a shortcut to opening Chrome with this flag set without having to open a terminal window, you can create a workflow in Automator, add a "Run Shell Script" item, and paste in the above script.

Saving the workflow as an application will create a clickable app. See this answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/281455/1512790

Answer (score 24):

Under the Chrome DevTools settings you enable:

Under Network -> Preserve Log
Under DevTools -> Auto-open DevTools for popups

Comment: The best answer IMO

Comment: good answer but explained for linux: Go to developer console. Go to the hamburger menu. click settings (or f1). in the network section check preserve log. in the devtools section check auto-open devtools for popups

Comment: On MacOS in Chrome 85 it is now under Settings -> Global section.

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366206/327074

Answer (score 18):

With the Developer Tools window visible, click the menu icon (the three vertical dots in the top right corner) and click **Settings**.

[image: Setting]

Under **Dev Tools**, check the **Auto-open DevTools for popups** option

[image: setting details]

Comment: Chrome Version 86 the setting is on the same place but named differently, so: Settings -> Preferences -> Global -> Auto-open DevTools for popups.

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366206/327074

Answer (score 14):

Answer for 2021:

1. Open the Developer Tool (CTRL+SHIFT+I on Windows)
2. Click the "Gear" icon. THe new Settings window will appear.

[image: Settings]

3. "Auto-open DevTools for popups" is now under "Preferences" section.

[image: actual location]

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366206/327074

Comment: Downvoted because stolen answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you use Visual Studio Code (vscode), using the very popular vscode chrome debug extension (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) you can setup a launch configuration file `launch.json` and specify to open the developer tool during a debug session.

This the `launch.json` I use for my React projects :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"],
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
    }
  ]
}
```

The important line is `"runtimeArgs": ["--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"],`

From vscode you can now type `F5`, Chrome opens your app and the console tab as well.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. [@VanAlbert's comment in the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#comment76864533_38366206) points in this direction, and this solves it. I'd missed off the `--` from the `runTimeArgs`.

Comment: works on Linux (Ubuntu 22.10 / Gnome)

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>F12</kbd> is easier than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Here's all the [DevTools open shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#shortcuts):

| OS | Elements | Console | Your last panel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows or Linux | Ctrl + Shift + **C** | Ctrl + Shift + **J** | F12 Ctrl + Shift + **I** |
| Mac | Cmd + Option + **C** | Cmd + Option + **J** | Fn + F12 Cmd + Option + **I** |

Comment: If you are on Windows or Linux

Comment: to hit f12 on a macbook, or pro you have to do fn+f12 (bottom left extreme + top right extreme), which is not comfortable for most keyboard users

Comment: Works great on linux... Another reason to switch. Did it on a Mac Pro, it's not perfect, but still way better than Apple OS

Answer (score 5):

Anyone looking to do this inside Visual Studio, this [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/644059/Run-Debug-with-new-browser-session-in-Visual-Studi) article will help.  Just add "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs" in the arguments box.  Works on 2017.

Comment: In case Code Project page goes away: you go to the Execute drop-down, select Browse With..., Add..., Program is something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe and Arguments: --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs -incognito (incognito being optional)

Answer (score 5):

Use `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag while running chrome from command line

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#auto

Comment: thanks ,It works on my computer.The premise is that all corresponding browser processes must be shut down first.

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36957422/327074

Comment: See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#comment76602920_36957422) on the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36957422/327074)

Comment: Further the link you point to suggests `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` for MacOS as in this [answer above from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329472/327074)

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for a similar solution. I really wanted to see the chrome output for the page load from a new tab (a form submission in my case).

The solution I actually used was to modify the form `target` attribute so that the form submission would occur in the current tab. Then I was able to capture the network request. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Yep,there is a way you could do it

1. Right click->Inspect->sources(tab)
2. Towards Your right there will be a "pause script execution button"
   [image: The button highlighted in the image directed by this link is the script execution button which can be paused or played as per necessity.Try it Yourself]

I hope it helps!Peace

- P.S:This is for the first time.From the second time onwards the dev tool loads automatically

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

1. Right-click your Google Chrome shortcut
2. Properties
3. Change Target to: **"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs**
4. Click ok
5. You will need to close all current chrome instances & end chrome processes in Task Manager. Or restart PC.

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36957422/327074

Answer (score 0):

On windows I try and succeed to make disappear DevTools opening @chrome opening or new tab opening

1. F12
2. DevTools settings
3. Click "Restore defaults and reload" button
   Close Chrome and check task manager to be shore that you close all Chrome processes.
   Open Chrome and no more DevTools :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open dev tools when redirecting, you can add a sleep function just before the `debugger` keyword.
Without this time sleep, auto-opening dev tool won't get opened.
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(script);` -- redirecting code in Spring e.g.
In your typescript app add

```
setTimeout(5000);
debugger
```

In my case that helped.

Answer (score -3):

You can open dock view settings and adjust the window as you want.
Screenshot attached.

[image: Dock_view_seetings]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry for the downvote, but I believe your answer is very far off the mark here.

Comment: I think the question is about how to get that window to automatically open, not about how to adjust that window.

Answer (score -6):

You can open Dev Tools (`F12` in Chrome) in new window by `clicking three, vertical dots` on the right bottom corner, and choose `Open as Separate Window`.

Comment: But I think the question is about how to get the window to automatically open, without needing extra clicks.