# Firefox keep developer tools open after popup window closes

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

A site has a popup window where you can send a message to someone. After the message is sent, the popup window closes. I'd like to see the requests made in the Firefox Developer window, but it closes when the popup closes. Is there a way to either keep the popup open or to keep the Dev tools open? This question is similar to [this question about Chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076590/chrome-dev-tools-is-it-possible-to-keep-open-even-after-window-closes).

Comment: In setting section of dev tools, you can check `Enable persistent logs`, then Dev tools wont clear console.

Comment: @Mehdi that doesn't help when the devtools window closes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Firefox Debugger to add an Event Listener for the *Load* > **load** event. In my case this prevented closing the window. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011428/1959568

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer did not work for me, it kept closing anyway.
However what *did* work was the solution presented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1411992/how-to-view-log-of-network-requests-across-tabs-in-firefox).

This involves using `about:config` to set the following values:

```
browser.link.open_newwindow                      1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction          0
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external    3
```

After this, the popup will open in the same window. Then, the script cannot close the window since it is not the creator.