# How to trace the POST info when browser automatically opens a new tab

Tags: post, python-requests, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use python requests to automatically capture csv data output from a site.

There is a button for download on the target page. It will pop up a message window for confirmation. Once I click ok, it will opens a new tab, download the csv, then the new tab automatically close.

The network tab in chrome dev is not able to capture any activity. I can't open the network tab on the new tab since it closes so quickly.

I found a discussion [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210468/chrome-dev-tools-how-to-trace-network-for-a-link-that-opens-a-new-tab) with similar issue, but it doesn't quite work on mine.
1) I don't know how to read the event log in chrome://net-internals/#events, but seems it doesn't have any POST info. 
2) Since it gives me a pop up first, I can't make it open in the same tab.

How do I get the POST info?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The new tab is opened for the final file URL usually, not the POST data, which is submitted in the original tab. So you should be able to see the request in devtools network panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm the original tab doesn't show any activity at all

Answer (score 0):

After some research, [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is good and simple solution here. You can find all POST info under inspector, webForms.