# Page load time in httpwatch for a new browser window. which opens up upon clicking an button in existing browser?

Tags: httpwatch

Guys do u know how to find the page load time in "httpwatch" when a new browser, which opens up upon clicking an button in existing browser?

Comment: Does this answer help? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480437/66911

Comment: Only for manual sake. but i am doing automation in IE