# Capture a network request sent immediately by a page opened in a new tab in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I need to capture a request in IE11 Network Tab, but it is sent almost immediately after the page loads, and the page itself opens in a new tab, so by the time I have opened DevTools with F12 and then enabled Network Capturing with F5, the request has already happened and is not captured.

Similar to [Chrome Dev Tools: How to trace network for a link that opens a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210468/chrome-dev-tools-how-to-trace-network-for-a-link-that-opens-a-new-tab), but for IE11.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page again after opening the dev tools on that newly opened page? Did that work? Other than that I did not get any way to capture the network trace for new window in IE 11 browser.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The page closes on refresh so this is not an option. I need to capture the event immediately after the page opens in a new tab. Maybe IE has a way to turn on network capture even when Dev Tools are not opened?

Comment: As I did not get any other way to capture the network trace for the newly opened window in IE 11 using dev tools. I suggest you try to check with Fiddler. it may help you to trace the desired information when a new tab gets opened in the IE browser.