# Can the Network Panel in Chrome Developer Tools Log When Closed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have on several occasions run across problems where I want to see the request data for a http request made while I had the Chrome Developer Tools closed, for instance to detect if I request a just made is running slow or has failed completely.

Is there a way I can get Chrome to always track the data in Networking Panel so it's present when I open the Developer Tools without having to reload the page and make new requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not possible directly.

You have to have DevTools open for it to log requests.  There is a work-around though: This is similar to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178918 - use remote debugging locally (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote).

Answer (score 7):

As an option, you can use `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag when launching Chrome.

(originally proposed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36957422/1300910) answer)