# Firefox / Chrome Debugger - Open Automatically

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an application, and I need to be able launch chrome/firefox with dev tools running. Does anyone know if there is a way to set dev tools to open on new tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible with Chrome DevTools right now (also see [Automatically open Chrome developer tools when new tab/new window is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened))

Not sure about Firefox at the moment, but I could not find anything that could lead to a positive response.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome added the option to "Auto-open DevTools for popups" in early 2016. I'm seeing the option in Chrome 51.

Open DevTools
Hit F1 to open settings
Scroll all the way to the bottom, and the option is under "DevTools"

Answer (score 4):

For Firefox:

You can use the commandline flag `--devtools` ([introduced in Firefox 45](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226744)) to start Firefox with the developer toolbar open. This works with or without specifying an URL to open.

Note, however, that it does not work when the invocation opens a new tab in an already running instance of Firefox (the default behavior if Firefox is already running). If you already have an instance running, you will have to launch Firefox with flag `--no-remote`. In that case you will usually also need `-P` to specify the alternative profile to start with, because the default profile will typically be in use.

---

However, `--devtools` only applies to the window/tab opened upon startup. There does not appear to be an option to automatically open the developer tools in new windows/tabs opened later, as in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add this command at the end of the exec Google-chrome file in your Linux system:

```
--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

As it is here: in the /usr/bin/... directory you will find chrome or dev version.
Or simply just create the shortcut to open your browser the same way for firefox --devtools

Comment: Additional detail found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#36957422