# How to keep 'Inspect Element' when opening a new tab

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to inspect a page in order to program a crawler.

The problem is: the site always opens a new tab and I can't see what is going down since 'Inspect Element' doesn't start automatically.

I'm looking for a solution in which my 'Inspect Element' would be turned on for every page I visit without having to press Ctrl + shift + I. Is it possible?

It looks like a trivial thing, but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically open Chrome developer tools when new tab/new window is opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened)

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a tab automatically inspect. My solution is to use new tab inspect in chrome bookmarks. copy and paste this: **javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0** into the url bookmark bar. After clicking edit. Click save then you should edit the page.

I hoped that helped.