# launch dedicated DevTools for Node.js from command-line

Tags: node.js, command-line, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I wondering how to launch "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" directly from the (windows or linux) command-line, without using `chrome://inspect` url then `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` button ?

My aim is to automatically run debugger for node.js:

```
launchDedicatedDevToolsForNode();
require('inspector').open(null, null, true); // sync
debugger;
```

note:
The underlying command, just behind the click handler of "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" link is:

```
chrome.send("open-node-frontend")
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened/36957422#36957422

Comment: unfortunately, question 12212504 is not about node.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your extension on chrome and run the command there

`chrome.send("open-node-frontend")`

Answer (score -2):

Chrome provides argument `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` to open the developer tools via cli.

Inorder to run dedicated dev tools via node.js process, Use `child_process execFile()` method. Check out the following snippet.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFileSync;

function launchChrome(path, hostUrl) {
    try {
        let args = [];
        args.push(hostUrl);
        args.push('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'); 
        execFile(path, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

//launchChrome(`C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`, '127.0.0.1:8000');
```

Note: Tested and working in Windows

Comment: Your answer is for opening "web" devTools, my aim is to open "dedicated DevTools for Node" to debug the node.js program

Comment: Just for understanding, VS Code and Webstorm already having debug mode right. What is the differnce between them and "dedicated DevTools for Node" ?

Comment: You can open devTools to debug the web page (F12) and you can open devTools to debug running node.js programs (chrome://inspect then click "Open dedicated DevTools for Node"

Comment: Hey @FranckFreiburger  `chrome://inspect then click "Open dedicated DevTools for Node"` -> Did you find a quicker way to do this?