# Developer panel keeps opening in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript

I am no developer or coder I'm just struggling to find someone that can help fix my pc.

My problem is - when I open either a chroome browser or internet explorer browser the panel on the right-hand side appears with all the coding info etc. In IE browser the browser is unstable and cannot be used.  I have updated from windows 8.1 to latest Windows 10. When I press the .x. on the developer pane the box closes and the pc works fine. It just returns every time I open a browser.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You can check settings described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366206/1309377

Comment: Good morning, thanks for your speedy response. Unfortunately, the problem persists after using your advice.

Comment: I would try reinstalling the browser then, I don't think that is normal behavior.

Comment: Hi, I have reinstalled all browsers including Firefox, I have reset edge as well. Also, I am unable to get out of selective startup, every time I try to get normal startup it reverts back to selective. When I restart the machine the easy flash bios screen shows up and I have to exit this to get the computer to continue. I have flashed the bios with the latest file from Asus.