# Is there a JS instruction to open the browser developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, safari-web-inspector

I know about the `debugger` keyword: it works as a breakpoint **if the developer tools are already open**.

But is there a way to programmatically instruct the web browser to open the developer tools? I've cruised through the MDN docs but haven't found anything.

The use case would be that I need to debug a part of a web that gets opened in a new tab. I can't open it in the same tab and by the time I hit F12 I've already missed the code I'm trying to debug.

Comment: You can start most browsers with command line arguments or configure to automatically open dev tools on all new tabs. Does this help: [Automatically open Chrome developer tools when new tab/new window is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212504/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened#38366206)?

Comment: Add `alert()` just before the code u need to debug. This will stop JS execution and provides you with ample of time to press F12 and open dev tools.